# How to bulk rename numbered files?

Tags: windows-8.1, filenames, batch-rename

I have two folders in Windows 8.1. The first folder, `a`, has 50 `.jpg` files numbered `01.jpg` through to `50.jpg`. My second folder, `b`, has the same amount of `.jpg` files named in the exact same manner.

My goal is to merge these two folders, but rename the files in `b` `51.jpg` through to `100.jpg` so that they stay in the same order.

Comment: This question on SoftwareRecs.SE is relevant. The answers there might help: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11389/6834

Answer (score 13):

1. Select all the files from a folder. Rename the first file from the selection as a- numbering will take place on its own.
2. Similarly rename b folder as b-
3. Then move files from b folder to a. (Asuming you have sort on name)
4. Again rename files as img- 
   You will have the numbering as img-1.....

Comment: It matters which file is the first to get renamed, so it'd be good instruct renaming the first file in the selection, given that it's sorted.

Comment: -1 cause it is simply a solution to do it manually, which in my opinion has nothing to do with a super user...

Comment: @BeowulfOF You could probably use voice command to "automate" it a bit more. It might be a bit cumbersome, but it still gets the job done and it's probably the easiest/quickest solution that doesn't require any specific or additional setup.

Comment: manually renaming 100 files is definitely slower than using a script and onboard-tools... easiest maybe.

Comment: @BeowulfOF Typing the new name happens once... The other selected files will automatically get updated. It's actually much faster (mostly mouse work) and safer (supported by the undo button) for many than editing and running a script.

Comment: I had no idea any GUI file browser had multi-file rename via selection semantics like this.  Will have to try that in some GNU/Linux ones.  (or just keep using `prename s/foo/bar/ *.jpg` to throw perl regexes at my file renaming problems. :)

Answer (score 13):

Windows 8.1 have PowerShell build-in, so you can use something like this:

```powershell
1..50|Rename-Item -Path {'{0:00}.jpg'-f$_} -NewName {'{0:00}.jpg'-f($_+50)}
```

In the above, the first `0` in `{0:00}` specifies the parameter index, and the second `00` specifies the format as two digits padded with zeroes.

Answer (score 4):

This would probably be better asked on [SoftwareRecommendations.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). But here are my recommendations.

---

I have used the free [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) on many occasions and found it to be very helpful. It's a little cluttered but extremely powerful.

[image: Bulk Rename Utility]

---

There is also PowerRename from Microsoft as part of their open source [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) suite. This is much less cluttered but slightly less powerful in some ways. However it does have support for RegEx renaming!

[image: PowerRename]

Comment: +1 for this. This is also my go-to tool for bulk renaming. The beauty of this tool is that one can 'preview' the result first, and the filelist pane allows renaming "all files but one/N" easily: Ctrl-A then just Ctrl-Click to unselect those you don't want to rename.

Comment: +1 for informing me about https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.  I had no idea that existed.

Answer (score 3):

Highly recommend IrfanView. It has the most amazing customization for bulk renaming files.

More details here: http://www.irfanview.com/faq.htm#Q13

Answer (score 2):

This is old and maybe too complex, but in CMD.exe you could solve it like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET COUNTER=1
FOR %%A IN ("a","b") DO (
    SET FOLDER=%%A
    FOR /F %%F IN ('DIR /B /ON !FOLDER!') DO (
        SET FILE=%%F
        COPY !FOLDER!\%%F c\!COUNTER!!FILE:~-4!
        SET /A COUNTER= !COUNTER! + 1
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend http://www.advancedrenamer.com/ as an alternative "easy-button" answer.  I actually use it all the time for batch-renames where I need a certain pattern, or need to remove silliness from other people's mashed-up filenames  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Niki above use DOS or the CMD utility.

In DOS  `C:\FolderA>`     (move to folder with A files)
Rename all the files in one go      `REN \*.jpg A-\*.jpg`

go to B folder using CD - change directory
Rename all the files in one go     `REN \*.jpg B-\*.jpg`

Then copy b-files to A folder.
`Copy B\*.jpg c:\FolderA\`